# Uncaught TypeError: data[option] is not a function bootstrap.js:1215

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-lightbox

I'm getting the following error using the bootstrap lightbox from [here](http://ashleydw.github.io/lightbox/):

`Uncaught TypeError: data[option] is not a function bootstrap.js:1215`

I've copied all files directory and haven't altered any parameters.

This is my code:

JS Linking:

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
 <script src="/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
 <script src="/js/bootstrap-lightbox.js"></script>

 <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap-theme.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap-social.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap-lightbox.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/font-awesome.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap-override.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fonts.example.com/custom-font.css">
```

Gallery:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <h1 class="page-header">Portfolio</h1>
    </div><?php
         $images = glob($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/img/gallery/*.{jpg,png,gif}', GLOB_BRACE);
         $imageCount = count($images);
          if($imageCount == 0) {
             echo "There are currently no images in this gallery.";
             }
             else if($imageCount !== 0) {
             $counter = 1;
         foreach($images as $image) {
          echo "<div class='col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-6 thumb'> \n\r";
         echo "<a data-toggle='lightbox' data-title='A random title' data-footer='A custom footer text' href='http://img.example.com/gallery/".basename($image)."' class='thumbnail'><img src='http://img.example.com/gallery/thumb.php?src=" . basename($image) . "&w=400&h=300&a=c' alt='Jolly Roger PCS Gallery Image' title='One Call Does It All' class='img-responsive'></a> \n\r";
         echo "</div> \n\r \n\r \r\n";
         }
       }
    ?>
  </div>
</div>
```

And the output of the gallery script for an image:

```
<div class='col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-6 thumb'> 

<a data-toggle='lightbox' data-title='A random title' data-footer='A custom footer text' href='http://img.example.com/gallery/10177464_1495074060751956_373648277891171115_n.jpg' class='thumbnail'><img src='http://img.example.com/gallery/thumb.php?src=10177464_1495074060751956_373648277891171115_n.jpg&w=400&h=300&a=c' alt='Jolly Roger PCS Gallery Image' title='One Call Does It All' class='img-responsive'></a> 

</div>
```

And finally the JS at the end of page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).on('click', '[data-toggle="lightbox"]', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).ekkoLightbox();
});
        </script>
```

The script is working to an extent. When I click a thumbnail image the lightbox fires and the loading image appears, but the full size image of the icon never does.

The data-types all appear to be in the right spot so I don't know what is causing this error. I tried a search and didn't come up with any results.

Comment: Can you put it in jsfiddle or codepen

Comment: What do you mean? That's the order everything has to be in to my knowledge.

Comment: Load the lightbox js before jquery

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason behind the error is incompatibility between versions of bootstrap and bootstrap lightbox plugin.

Check working demo [here](http://codepen.io/jpI/pen/ZpaxQx):

```js
$(document).on('click', '[data-toggle="lightbox"]', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).ekkoLightbox();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="https://unsplash.it/1200/768.jpg?image=251" data-toggle="lightbox">
    <img src="https://unsplash.it/600.jpg?image=251" class="img-fluid">
</a>
```

If you are using bootstrap version 3.x.x then include the following assets:

[image]

If you are using bootstrap version 4.x.x then include the following assets:

[image]

Comment: I copied those files for bootstrap 3 and now the error is gone but the image still doesn't load. The loading image doesn't appear either but I get the grey overlay.

Comment: Check with the image resources

Answer (score 1):

Change your order.

```
<script src="/js/bootstrap-lightbox.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

Comment: I did that.
My loading image stopped working and console showed the following error:

`Uncaught TypeError: $(...).ekkoLightbox is not a function(anonymous function) @ (index):396dispatch @ jquery.min.js:5y.handle @ jquery.min.js:5`