# bootstrap.js?18ce:1215 Uncaught TypeError: data[option] is not a function in laravel

Tags: jquery, laravel, bootstrap-modal

Iam getting this error when i want to submit the modal in  using ajax call. I don't know what is causing this error. I tried a search and didn't come up with any results.can someone help me?

```
my js code in html file

     <script src="/js/app.js">

    </script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#btn_add').click(function(){
               var url = "http://localhost:8000/home";
                $('#btn-save').val("add");
                $('#frmPost').trigger("reset");
                $('#myModal').modal('show');
                $('#btn-save').click(function(e){

                    $.ajaxSetup({
                            headers: {
                                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                            }

                    })

                    var formData = {
                            'title':"sdsdsd",
                            'description' :"dssdhjsdjs"
                        }


                    $.ajax({ //line 28
                            url: url,
                            type: 'POST',
                            data: { userData: formData },
                            success: function()
                            {
                                //alert("Settings has been updated successfully.");
                                  $('#myModal').modal('close');
                            }
                    });

                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

My controller:

```
      <?php

       namespace App\Http\Controllers;

       use Illuminate\Http\Request;

    class HomeController extends Controller
    {
        /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    /**
     * Show the application dashboard.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return view('home');
    }
     public function addPost(Request $request)
    {
      var_dump($request->all());
      return view('home');

    }
}
```

Comment: can you provide the controller function/s?

Comment: yeah i edited my code.i think the error is not with controller.it is with bootstrap and jquery related.bit i didnt know how to solve it

Comment: see a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39735074/uncaught-typeerror-dataoption-is-not-a-function-bootstrap-js1215?rq=1

Comment: yeah i have seen it.but id idnt using any bootsrap and jquery links.iam using default laravel bootsrap and jquery.

Comment: i didn't know laravel comes with default bootstrap & jquery

Comment: i dont know exactly as i ws new to laravel .i have "bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.7",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "jquery": "^3.1.0",             in my package.json file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127513/discussion-between-user3860618-and-madalin-ivascu).